# Selecting multiple cells in Silverlight 4 Datagrid

Tags: .net, silverlight-4.0, datagrid

I have some 6 columns in Silverlight 4 Datagrid. On each cell in the data grid, we have some custom controls got displayed. Now i should allow the user to select one control from each of the columns. Once they select one control from each columns, then will go and click on OK button to preform some work. One note is, He might choose different cells from different columns. They might not be from the same row.

How can we implement this kind of functionality in the grid. Any suggestions on, how should we proceed with this problem. Is there any way to select multiple cells in Silverlight 4 Datagrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" />
```